# SQL FLOAT to Hours/Minutes

Tags: sql

I have a float value that is derived from dates being subtracted. How do I convert this float value into minutes? Perferably if I could convert it into hours and minutes otherwise just minutes....

For example here are some values I have:

```
4.12676944443956

3.91463738425955

0.102466473770619

0.0308067515434232

0.0564043209888041
```

The answer to Pauls question is that these are days.

Comment: What are these values?  Days, weeks, years, microseconds?

Comment: If you don't know the answer to Paul's question then post the two dates used to get each of these values so people can determine the answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these values indicate days and the precision you want to achieve is minutes. The best possible way for you to do this would be to write a function to multiply this value with 1440 (number of minutes in a day) and round off the places past the decimal. I may be missing something though since the answer cannot be this simple.

Answer (score 0):

If that's days and fractions thereof,

```
Hours = :date_value * 24;
Minutes = :date_value * 24 * 60

Integer Hours     = trunc(:date_value * 24)
Remaining Minutes = mod(:date_value * 24, 60) 

Integer Days        = trunc(:date_value)
Remaining Int Hours = mod(:date_value, 24)
Remaining Minutes   = mod(:date_value, 24 * 60);
```

In Oracle, the "remainder" function is MOD(number, divisor).

Answer (score 0):

When I do a query in SQL server to subtract two dates and cast as a float it gives me the result in days.  So to convert your float to the number of minutes multiply by 1440.